# Updated pyramid model directory structure now sessions are broken

Tags: session, python-3.x, pyramid, pickle

**background**

So I have a Pyramis app with a whole lot of models that relate to each other in different ways. These models were initially kept in a bunch of different files according to their general roles. For example I had a file called auth_models.py that contained the definition for User and Group.

I've been battling to deal with imports and suchlike because all the model files relate to each other in such a complex way so I gave in and placed all of them in the same file. And then I updated all my import statements elsewhere so everything should work.

Now whenever I try to access any view at all I get an internal server error. It turns out that the error is caused by the fact that auth_models.py no longer exists. The error is coming from a `picklie.loads` statement so I figure there is some session info being loaded that is no longer working. The full error message as well as my session settings are included at the end of this question.

**question**

If my assumption is correct, how would I get Pyramid to 'forget' the last sessions in a safe way?

If my assumption is incorrect, what's the best way to fix this? I don't want to revert to my old directory structure because that causes it's own problems...

**settings**

```
session.type = file
session.data_dir = %(here)s/data/sessions/data
session.lock_dir = %(here)s/data/sessions/lock
session.key = ******
session.secret = *****
session.cookie_on_exception = true
session.auto = true
session.timeout = 1800
```

**error**

```
2013-04-08 10:24:15,642 ERROR [waitress][Dummy-2] Exception when serving /
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-1.0.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/toolbar.py", line 122, in toolbar_tween
response = _handler(request)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-1.0.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/panels/performance.py", line 55, in resource_timer_handler
result = handler(request)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid/tweens.py", line 21, in excview_tween
response = handler(request)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid_tm-0.7-py3.3.egg/pyramid_tm/__init__.py", line 82, in tm_tween
reraise(*exc_info)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid_tm-0.7-py3.3.egg/pyramid_tm/compat.py", line 13, in reraise
raise value
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid_tm-0.7-py3.3.egg/pyramid_tm/__init__.py", line 63, in tm_tween
response = handler(request)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid/router.py", line 161, in handle_request
response = view_callable(context, request)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid/config/views.py", line 345, in rendered_view
result = view(context, request)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid/config/views.py", line 462, in _class_requestonly_view
inst = view(request)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/mega/wsgi/pyramidapp/pyramidapp/views/basic_views.py", line 10, in __init__
BaseView.__init__(self,request)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/mega/wsgi/pyramidapp/pyramidapp/views/class_base_view.py", line 15, in __init__
BaseView.session_init(request)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/mega/wsgi/pyramidapp/pyramidapp/views/class_base_view.py", line 62, in session_init
if not request.session.__contains__(sKey):
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid/decorator.py", line 39, in __get__
val = self.wrapped(inst)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid/request.py", line 350, in session
return factory(self)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid/session.py", line 204, in __init__
value = signed_deserialize(cookieval, self._secret)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid/session.py", line 82, in signed_deserialize
return pickle.loads(pickled)
ImportError: No module named 'pyramidapp.models.auth_models'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid/mako_templating.py", line 211, in __call__
result = template.render_unicode(**system)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Mako-0.7.3-py3.3.egg/mako/template.py", line 421, in render_unicode
as_unicode=True)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Mako-0.7.3-py3.3.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 767, in _render
**_kwargs_for_callable(callable_, data))
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Mako-0.7.3-py3.3.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 799, in _render_context
_exec_template(inherit, lclcontext, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Mako-0.7.3-py3.3.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 825, in _exec_template
callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)
File "pyramid_debugtoolbar_templates_toolbar_dbtmako", line 111, in render_body
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-1.0.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/panels/request_vars.py", line 42, in content
if hasattr(self.request, 'session'):
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid/decorator.py", line 39, in __get__
val = self.wrapped(inst)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid/request.py", line 350, in session
return factory(self)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid/session.py", line 204, in __init__
value = signed_deserialize(cookieval, self._secret)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid/session.py", line 82, in signed_deserialize
return pickle.loads(pickled)
ImportError: No module named 'pyramidapp.models.auth_models'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/waitress-0.8.2-py3.3.egg/waitress/channel.py", line 329, in service
task.service()
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/waitress-0.8.2-py3.3.egg/waitress/task.py", line 173, in service
self.execute()
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/waitress-0.8.2-py3.3.egg/waitress/task.py", line 380, in execute
app_iter = self.channel.server.application(env, start_response)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid/router.py", line 251, in __call__
response = self.invoke_subrequest(request, use_tweens=True)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid/router.py", line 227, in invoke_subrequest
response = handle_request(request)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-1.0.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/toolbar.py", line 135, in toolbar_tween
toolbar.process_response(response)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-1.0.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/toolbar.py", line 56, in process_response
vars, request=request)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid/renderers.py", line 88, in render
return helper.render(value, None, request=request)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid/renderers.py", line 557, in render
result = renderer(value, system_values)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid/mako_templating.py", line 219, in __call__
reraise(MakoRenderingException(errtext), None, exc_info[2])
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid/compat.py", line 131, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid/mako_templating.py", line 211, in __call__
result = template.render_unicode(**system)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Mako-0.7.3-py3.3.egg/mako/template.py", line 421, in render_unicode
as_unicode=True)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Mako-0.7.3-py3.3.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 767, in _render
**_kwargs_for_callable(callable_, data))
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Mako-0.7.3-py3.3.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 799, in _render_context
_exec_template(inherit, lclcontext, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Mako-0.7.3-py3.3.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 825, in _exec_template
callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)
File "pyramid_debugtoolbar_templates_toolbar_dbtmako", line 111, in render_body
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-1.0.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/panels/request_vars.py", line 42, in content
if hasattr(self.request, 'session'):
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid/decorator.py", line 39, in __get__
val = self.wrapped(inst)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid/request.py", line 350, in session
return factory(self)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid/session.py", line 204, in __init__
value = signed_deserialize(cookieval, self._secret)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid/session.py", line 82, in signed_deserialize
return pickle.loads(pickled)
pyramid.mako_templating.MakoRenderingException: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid/mako_templating.py", line 211, in __call__
result = template.render_unicode(**system)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Mako-0.7.3-py3.3.egg/mako/template.py", line 421, in render_unicode
as_unicode=True)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Mako-0.7.3-py3.3.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 767, in _render
**_kwargs_for_callable(callable_, data))
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Mako-0.7.3-py3.3.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 799, in _render_context
_exec_template(inherit, lclcontext, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Mako-0.7.3-py3.3.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 825, in _exec_template
callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-1.0.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/templates/toolbar.dbtmako", line 60, in render_body
${panel.content()|n}
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-1.0.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/panels/request_vars.py", line 42, in content
if hasattr(self.request, 'session'):
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid/decorator.py", line 39, in __get__
val = self.wrapped(inst)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid/request.py", line 350, in session
return factory(self)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid/session.py", line 204, in __init__
value = signed_deserialize(cookieval, self._secret)
File "/home/sheena/WORK/mega-3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg/pyramid/session.py", line 82, in signed_deserialize
return pickle.loads(pickled)
ImportError: No module named 'pyramidapp.models.auth_models'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have stored some of your model instances in a session cookie, which uses `pickle` to serialize and deserialize that data.

Because you moved the model to another module, pickle can no longer load the session data.

You can do two things:

- If you don't care about the session data, simply delete your session cookie. Use your browser tools to delete the cookie manually, perhaps delete all cookies for your site.
- Create an alias for the model in the old location. Create a `pyramidapp.models.auth_models` module that simply imports the models that *used* to be there. This module does not need to be imported by anything else, `pickle` will load it for you when needed.

Any future sessions will be created with the new location of your models, this affects only old session data.

Comment: I cleared my cookies before I asked but it turns out I didn't clear all of them. Thanks